# underwater bug identification

Tags: species-identification, limnology

There is a small pond outside my work (more like a run-off ditch from a parking lot). Once a year it gets swarmed by this tiny bug. I am having some trouble identifying it. The biggest ones were about 1mm in size. I found these in Indiana. They are tan/light brown and the bigger ones had small 1-2 small black marks on their backs. Sorry for the blurry images, They were kinda quick and hard to capture from the camera on my stereomicroscope.
Here is a macroscale video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/1BEN7NP8okWqGKVh9

Here are some microscope photos:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please update with 1) location, 2) more details (e.g. size, coloration, notable features), and better photo(s). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to tell from the photographs, but from them having a small "beak-like" structure (3rd photo), I think this is likely to be a Water Flea (*[Daphnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnia)* species), which is a common, cosmopolitan genus of small zoo-plankton.

They are typically about 1-5 mm (0.039–0.197 in) long and actively swim through the water, collecting algae to feed on.

Comment: If you look at the macroscale video, they seem to move smoothly and in the direction that the oval points. If you look at this youtube video, daphnia seem to move sideways and in jumps like a jellyfish: https://youtu.be/sD9Tg0Qw-Yg?t=48

Comment: @user1402154 is could be that you have more than 1 organism type in your sample - the 3rd photo could easily be a different species from the other photos, given differences in shape and gut position. Have you looked at pages on common microorganisms in pond water? there might be something that rings a bell for you.

Comment: Ive googled it a bunch. Is there a particular resource you recommend?

Comment: @user1402154 These guys seem OK: [https://www.microscopyu.com/galleries/dic-phase-contrast/pond-life](https://www.microscopyu.com/galleries/dic-phase-contrast/pond-life)

Comment: it was bigger than most of those. I am starting to wonder if they're amphipod or amphipod larvae. They appear in the spring during the flooding and then disappear for the rest of the year. Maybe theyre terrestial amphipods with a water/larva stage?

they could totally be sandhopper larvae